# Group By clause not showing the same row values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with the following columns and data

```
filename1       filename2       hd
S5000L00.dat    S5111L01.dat    0.46
S5111L00.dat    S5000L01.dat    0.46
S5001L00.dat    S5002L01.dat    0.47
S5002L00.dat    S5001L01.dat    0.47
S5003L00.dat    S5002L01.dat    0.38
S5002L00.dat    S5003L01.dat    0.38
S5000L00.dat    S5000L01.dat    0.21*
S5002L00.dat    S5002L01.dat    0.42
S5002L01.dat    S5000L00.dat    0.42
S5001L00.dat    S5000L03.dat    0.24
```

Now I want to group by **filename1** and view the minimum hd for each file

When I run the following query

```
Select filename1, filename2, min(hd) as hd 
from data group by filename1 
order by hd asc;
```

I get the followiing result

```
filename1       filename2       hd
S5000L00.dat    S5111L01.dat    0.21*
S5001L00.dat    S5002L01.dat    0.24
S5003L00.dat    S5002L01.dat    0.38
S5002L00.dat    S5001L01.dat    0.38
S5002L01.dat    S5000L00.dat    0.42
S5111L00.dat    S5000L01.dat    0.46
```

The starred rows are where is the problem. In the table the filename2 is S5000L01.dat but in the resultset the **filname2** is S5111L01.dat . I want the same filename but I couldn't get to form a query.

Thanks

Comment: That's because your `group by` usage is invalid SQL. But instead of rejecting it MySQL prefers to return random (they call it indeterminate) data. You want `group by filename1, filename2`. See here for details: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  g.filename1,
  data.filename2,
  g.hd
FROM
  data
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT 
        filename1, 
        min(hd) AS hd 
      FROM 
        data 
      GROUP BY 
        filename1) AS g
      ON data.filename1=g.filename1
      AND data.hd=g.hd
ORDER BY g.hd ASC
```

the reason why your query isn't working: you're relying on MySQL [`GROUP BY` extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). This extension allows to mix non-grouped columns with grouping conditions, but **server is free to chose any row**. That's why there's no guarantee that desired `filename2` will be selected. In fact, your original query isn't valid in normal SQL, it's MySQL feature - but I strongly recommend you do not rely on it.

Comment: Thanks @Alma I think I need to dig deeper into database. And your solution works and now I understand why your works and mine not.

Comment: There is one more question. The data I have shown you is very small. Tha actual data that I have is around 20 million rows. Will join make the query slower.

Comment: Quick answer: _try it_. My though: since you're using subquery - I'm afraid, it won't be fast - because it's a row set in memory and it won't be indexed

Comment: tHE Query worked outside. But when I wrote it inside a procedure with a cursor the cursor is always empty. Is there something I dont' know

Comment: I suggest you to ask separate question with full code & data provided